# Hide Kinect hand pointer (KFW2)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, kinect

Maybe this is easy and so newbie I should be ashamed to ask, but here I go:

How can I hide the hand pointer?

Thanks! & Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer is a bit late but here is what i did to remove the hand pointer.

Create an empty png file with the size of 548 x 2740 px, then copy it to your project and set the CursorSpriteSheet to this Resource like this:

```
MainWindow.kinectRegion.CursorSpriteSheetDefinition = new CursorSpriteSheetDefinition(new System.Uri("pack://application:,,,/Assets/CursorSpriteSheetEmpty.png"), 4, 20, 137, 137);
```

You can also take the example png file from the SDK v2 Samples( it's located in ControlsBasicWPF)

As mentioned before: don't forget to set the png file as "Resource" in files properties in VS.

Regards